# kubeadm init fails when using cri-o

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I've been following this doc to deploy kubernetes https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/

After launching the "kubeadm init" command and during its excecution, this is the output:

> [kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
>   Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
>           timed out waiting for the condition
>   This error is likely caused by:
>           - The kubelet is not running
>           - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)
>   If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
>           - 'systemctl status kubelet'
>           - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'
>   Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
>   To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI, e.g. docker.
>   Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
>           - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
>           Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
>           - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'
>   error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
>   To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

It runs fine if I install docker and switch the runtime to docker instead of "remote" and "systemd".

I've tried several things, but this is the content of my last try:

> cat etc/sysconfig/kubelet
>
> KUBELET_ARGS="--container-runtime=remote
>   --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock --runtime-request-timeout=10m --cluster_domain=topota.madre"
>
> systemctl cat kubelet
>
> # /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service [Unit] Description=kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent Documentation=https://kubernetes.io/docs/
>
> [Service] ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet Restart=always
>   StartLimitInterval=0 RestartSec=10
>
> [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target
>
> # /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
>   # Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+ [Service]
>   Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf
>   --kubeconfig=/etc/ Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
>   # This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS var
>   EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
>   # This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user shoul
>   # the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sour
>   EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/kubelet ExecStart=
>   ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS
>   $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
>
> cat /var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
>
> is empty right now

Cri-O service ir running ok and Docker is not installed.

- kubelet version --short -> Client Version: v1.17.2
- kubeadm version -o short -> v1.17.2
- cat /etc/redhat-release -> CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
- crictl version -> ["Version:  0.1.0","RuntimeName: cri-o","RuntimeVersion:  1.15.1-2.el7","RuntimeApiVersion:  v1alpha1"]
- crictl info -> {"status": {"conditions": [{"type": "RuntimeReady","status": true,"reason": "","message": ""},{"type": NetworkReady","status": true,"reason": "","message": ""}]}}
- grep -i cgroup_manager /etc/crio/crio.conf -> cgroup_manager = "systemd"
- lsmod | grep -i "overlay\|br_netfilter" -> ["br_netfilter","overlay"] (both ok).
- Other "extra args tested" (/etc/sysconfig/kubelet)

> KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd
>   --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock

- Full output of some commands:
  -> "kube admin init --upload-certs" -> https://pastebin.com/isbAynEg
  -> "while true ; do systemctl status kubelet ; sleep 1 ; done" -> https://pastebin.com/9pgtDMNu
  -> "cat /etc/sysctl.d/99-kubernetes-cri.conf" -> ["net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1","net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1","net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1"]
  -> "journalctl -xeu kubelet" -> https://pastebin.com/qreJyhsu (this one has some things like "aws credentials" which i dont understand and not sure if are the reason or not for the errors).

Any help please?

Comment: What's the output when you follow instructions bellow:

The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled) If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands: - 'systemctl status kubelet' - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Comment: I just added the links to pastebin with those outputs. I did not see anything conclusive in them, but there are some interesting lines that I may be overseeing.

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: I've just added the info to the original question. Thx for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running crio 1.17.0-rc1 with kubernetes 1.17.1 on RHEL7/CENTOS7.  One thing I had to do was build crio 1.17 myself because there was no package available and I read the version should match (crio 1.17 and k8 1.17).

I am using systemd as the cgroup driver. I'm not sure what your issue might be, but my setup goes like this:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/kubelet
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock --cloud-provider=external
```

My kubeadm init line is (I'm using an env variable to set the control plain endpoint):

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --control-plane-endpoint {{ lookup('env','master_lb_ip_address') }}:6443 --upload-certs >> $HOME/log/init-cluster.log
```

I also edited /etc/crio/crio.conf to set systemd as the cgroup manager.

```
cgroup_manager = "systemd"
```

Also make sure you are enabling the modules / sysconfig options specified on [this page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#cri-o).

```
modprobe overlay
modprobe br_netfilter

# Setup required sysctl params, these persist across reboots.
cat > /etc/sysctl.d/99-kubernetes-cri.conf <<EOF
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables  = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward                 = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
EOF

sysctl --system
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Please review the question as I've updated it with new info and also with the outputs of running kubeadm init with your parameters. Still no luck :/

Comment: What's your cri-o version?  Can you show output from `crictl version` and `crictl info`?

Comment: Hi LArntz. I've just added the info to the original question. Thank you!

Comment: OK. I think this might be your problem....

`crictl version -> ["Version: 0.1.0","RuntimeName: cri-o","RuntimeVersion: 1.15.1-2.el7","RuntimeApiVersion: v1alpha1"]`

See the [compatibilty matrix on the cri-o github](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o).  You need to be running a version of cri-o that matches the kubernetes version. 

If there's not binary version available for your OS it's pretty easy [to build](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/master/tutorials/setup.md) (but I've heard of issues with redhat/centos 8).

Comment: Makes sense and matches your original answer. I overviewed this point as it is not mentioned in the "getting started" kubernetes doc. I'll try to build the package and comment here the output. Thank you!

Comment: That's a good point. If their docs are opensource a pull request might be helpful to others.

Comment: That was it!!! Also, in cri-o github page it says that kubelet needs to be same version as cri-o (not mentioned in kubernetes doc for kubeadm install where only kubeadm and kubelet match is mentioned). I was not able to compile v1.17, so I just shortcut to run all in v1.15 (latest available in repo). Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! Happy your issue is resolved. 

I submitted a pull request for the kubernetes docs also so hopefully that will be updated soon.